# Hyperlink to Windows Special Folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I would like to email link in Outlook which opens *Devices and Printers*.  I can copy and paste the following into Start > Run or an Explorer address bar.

`C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}`

How can I create a hyperlink which opens *Devices and Printers*?

Comment: You should just be able to insert a link, and the url, would have string of text as the address.

Comment: Creating a link in the email doesn't work ("We can't find [...]") and neither does forwarding a `.lnk` file as Outlook deems it "potentially unsafe". You could instead give instructions on how to enter this into the Explorer address bar. If this is in a networked environment, you could create a shortcut in a network share. Finally, you could rename the `.lnk` file to a `.txt` file and give instructions for renaming it back.

Comment: If this was possible this would be very big security hole.

Comment: If this is possible, how would opening a special folder via a link be any different than opening via a shortcut? I don’t see the security hole risk here.